# What is/should be our take about code-debugging questions?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

As we are in an early stage beta and are still molding our scope and the culture, let's have a string of discussions regarding the same.  And, here's one:

**Should code debugging questions be welcome here?**

Or should we send them to SO? We, the mods have some opinions too. So, putting the question out there so that we can all discuss collectively.

Comment: I'd explicitly list in the question (or ask as separate, related questions?) particular cases, especially the borderline ones, like questions about: CI/CD pipeline failures caused by errors in the very sw product itself (build failures, for examples), custom scripts for devops use, etc. - this should help clarify whatever is the outcome decision and help with future reviews of such questions.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Very well!  Pl go ahead and raise a question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, it depends, on the code.  If the code in question is about building an extension for one of the many DevOps tools that are on-topic and the problem at hand appears to be as a result of that tools API then it should be allowed.

If the code has a gramatical error or is simply "why doesn't my code work" then it is off topic on SO and here.

If the code is part of a consumer application that serves requests from actual users then it is on topic for SO but off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend asking separate specific meta questions (ideally referencing this Q&A for context and inter-linking) about each particular case, especially for the borderline ones, for example questions about:

- CI/CD pipeline failures caused by errors in the very sw product itself (build failures, for examples)
- custom scripts for devops use

Collectively these Q&As should help:

- clarify whatever is the outcome decision and help with future reviews of such questions
- fill in the DevOps specific [on-topic](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) guidelines
- clarify some of the future DevOps customisation of the menu seen when flagging questions for closing
- clarify some of the future decision of which SE sites would be included in the DevOps list for off-topic question migration (well, SO in this particular case).